# Is this a predicative adjunct?

Tags: catenative-verbs, predicative-complement

> Harry swung at it with the bat to stop it from breaking his nose, and
>   sent it **zigzagging** away into the air. (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

‘Zigzagging’ seems to be a predicative adjunct as the case below. Can both be the same case?

> They served the coffee **blindfolded**. [predicative adjunct]
>   (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p529)

Comment: Probably, _zigzagging_ is not an adjunct, as _sent it zigzagging_ is different from _sent it_. _Away into the air_ is surely an adjunct.

Comment: I don't know what CGEL means by 'predicative adjunct'; but the two are very different. *Blindfolded* modifies the subject of its sentence (and maybe the verb as well); *zigzagging* modifies the object. But it is also arguably the head of what I can only describe as a participial clause, which is arguably a complement of *send*, if we read that in a causative sense: 'caused it to zigzag away'. You might consider asking that this be migrated to ELU where somebody who really understands this stuff might take it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally gave up trying to answer this myself and took the problem over to ELU. As I hoped, John Lawler [came through](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121522/24489).

The construction has apparently not been named, but JL suggests treating it as 
a **serial verb construction** (SVC) of two or more verbs in sequence, like *go swimming* or *Come help me!* He describes the construction in your example as [my **emphasis**]:

> ... the initial verb part of the serial verb is
>
> - an intransitive motion verb (go, come)
> - a transitive causative/inchoative of a motion verb (respectively: take, bring)
> - a transitive verb that entails some kind of induced motion (pluck, **send**, toss, drop, etc.)
>
> while the gerund* part normally describes some property of
>
> - the motion induced by the verb (lurching, **zigzagging**, spinning) [OR]
> - the object or person caused to move (muttering, shuddering, screaming, unmoving)
>
> In either case, it is the moving object that functions as subject of the gerund constituent.
>   * *I believe he uses* gerund *in the sense CGEL uses* gerund-participle.

He goes on to remark that this construction is 'discontinuous', like a "phrasal verb" where the second part of the verb comes after the object. Thus *sent it zigzagging* is analogous to *do it over* or *ask her out*.

Fascinating stuff. There seems to be a substantial literature on SVCs, but mostly about languages other than English (including your own). I did find [this article](http://www.stanford.edu/~zwicky/serial-verbs.pdf); section 2.1 is most relevant, but the conclusion is of great general relevance.

Do look at JL's answer for more detail. And I think you will particularly enjoy his following Comment about Harry Potter.

Comment: I’m very much appreciated your two-months dedicated answer. And I’m happy to get Prof. John Lawler’s article. : “Serial construction” is said in CGEL under the title of “Catenative Construction.” (p.1194-1245) and the name –– catenative verb –– is also said in Prof. Angela Downing’s (p.108). Yet your and Prof. JL’s explanation is more specific on the matter.